# Mongoose push multiple unique values in nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to push multiple values in a nested array of objects like this:

```
Schema.update(
    { _id: req.params.id},
    { $push: { content: { $each: req.body } } }
```

Being req.body something like this:

```
req.body = [{id: 1, name: 'foo'},{id: 2, name: 'bar'}]
```

Ensuring that none of them is already there, any way to use $ne property for multiple sub-elements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `$addToSet` with `$each` instead of `$push`. More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#each-modifier)

Comment: `$addToSet` works for simple arrays, doesn't work for an array of objects, there must be a way to specify which field you are comparing.